# Python Ignore exception and continue with the following item in a list

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

Good morning/afternoon/evening everybody!
I'm trying to code a discord bot that has aeronautical functionalities. One of them it's a command that answer the user with meteorological reports of a determined airport. I'm using an API for this to work.

Let´s say I have a list of airports that an user inputs:

```
airports = ["A","B","C"]
```

I have a function that splits the list and retrieves the information based on an API. That works fine.

The trouble comes here. Let's say that any of the airports listed does not exists/it's misspelled/etc.
How can I make the code ignore that and keep along with the another airports?

This is the code I'm working on:

```
for i in aeropuertos:
  finalizado = MetarBot.metarbot.Taf(i)
  await ctx.send(finalizado)
  time.sleep(0.5)
```

It processes airport "A" and it's all good. Outputs the data. When it comes to airport "B" it stops there. Is it any way to just ignore (or to pop a "Check your spelling!") that and continue with the next in list?

Already tried with **try and except**, but didn't work. Also tried with **contextlib.suppress**

EDIT1: API documentation: https://avwx.docs.apiary.io/#introduction/authentication

Comment: My feeling is that it may not be stopping due to an exception, but perhaps it got stuck. What is the specific line where it stops?

Comment: Can you provide documentation for the api you're using? Instead of consider this an error the API should return some kind of an "item not found" response. Check to see if it has a timeout argument.

Comment: @luizbarcelos Hi! This is how it works: You input a 4-letter code. Then it goes to the API and retrieves a dictionary. From there I extract a specific key ["raw"]. The code stops when it cannot retrieve that key for that unknown/misspelled aiport. I just edited the post adding the API reference, thank you for your answer!

Comment: @DvirH just edited the post with the API documentation, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to figure out how to do this. I kinda solved the question. I have some ideas on how to solve this. For e.g., having a text file checking if the name is correct before starting the API request.

But what I did is to identify the airport code that's wrong and give an answer of that.

```
try:
    a = 0
    for i in aeropuertos:
    finalizado = MetarBot.metarbot.Taf(i)
    await ctx.send(finalizado)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    a += 1
except:
      error = aeropuertos[a]
      await ctx.send(f"Error. {error.upper()} inválido/no se encuentra en la base de datos.")
```